Expo Google Login is working in Web and iOS but not Android, displaying 400:Invalid Access Blocked
My issue is the same as this one three years ago with no solution.
EXPO Google Sign In And Android app Issue
What happens is: I click "sign in with goolge", it will prompt me to choose an account, I select the account, spinner spins under "accounts.google.com", I am directed to google.com landing page. Only for Android , Web and iOS is fine.
Also same like this one
Expo App with Google Login is not redirecting to app
I am not using expo go
I am using
npx expo run:android

My Expo Setting for app.json is as follow
  "expo": {
    "name": "ConnexBiz",
    "slug": "ConnexBiz",
    "scheme": "ConnexBiz",

It work for Web and iOS but not Android and displaying this. Access Blocked :Authorization Error

I am using these versions, and already applied Redirect_URL in Google Developer Console

If I enable this it works ,but after login , it only redirect to google.com

